Why can open port (iptables) be closed?
We are using iptables on our Linux server. And the table looks like this:
$ sudo iptables -L -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8474
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8007
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1883
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
# ...

But the port 1883 seems to be closed (from my machine):
$ nmap -p 1883 mqtt.host.com
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-09-04 09:54 CEST
Nmap scan report for mqtt.host.com (...)
Host is up (0.014s latency).
rDNS record for ...: host.com

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
1883/tcp closed mqtt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds

I have opened port 1883 for mqtt by using sudo iptables -I INPUT 3 -p tcp --dport 1883 -j ACCEPT.
What am I doing wrong or what else do I need to do?

Is the MQTT service running on the server? If so, which address(es) is it listening on?

@StephenKitt oh yes, the mosquitto broker was listening on 1883, but just for localhost. I have fixed this, thanks!

you can watch "actively listening port" (cough) using as root ss -tlpn

The problem was not related to iptables, but to my configuration of the MQTT broker.
It was listening on 1883, but only for localhost. I have fixed this by removing this restriction and now the port is seen as open.
